# how to put FileUpload control in gridview while editing record

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I use griview propertied while editing or deleting records without coding

When I click on edit button my image is also converted into a TextBox control,
I want to take

> Fileupload control instead of textBox control.

For it which property shoule i set?

my code is as follow

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="197px" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductID" 
     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AllowPaging="True">
     <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" 
              InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" 
              SortExpression="ProductName" />
          <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Image" HeaderText="PHOTO">
              <ControlStyle Height="100px" Width="100px" />
          </asp:ImageField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
              SortExpression="status" />    
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is the code of SqlDataSource2:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringnewdb %>" 
            DeleteCommand="delete from Product where ProductID=@ProductID" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Product]" 
            UpdateCommand="update  Product set ProductName=@ProductName,Status=@Status where ProductID=@ProductID ">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="ProductID" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="ProductName" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ProductID" />
            </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`EditItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.edititemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and add the `FileUpload` control:

```
... other columns ...
</EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload id="FileUpload1"  runat="server">
   </asp:FileUpload>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
... other columns ...
```

Here's a tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx